# mapping outputs from one object to inputs in another in a delayed fashion

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple workflow/pipeline object in python where one can chain many functions together and execute them in the correct order. So, eventually I end up with a graph where the outputs from one function gets piped as input to another function and I wanted to be able to map these variables between functions. One way I thought I can do this is as follows:

```
class Node1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inputs = {}
        self.inputs['a'] = None
        self.inputs['b'] = None
        self.outputs = {}
        self.outputs['result'] = None

    def add_input(self, key, value):
        self.inputs[key] = value

    def run(self):
        self.outputs['result'] = 42

class Node2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inputs = {}
        self.inputs['num1'] = None
        self.outputs = {}
        self.outputs['num2'] = None

    def add_input(self, key, value):
        self.inputs[key] = value

    def run(self):
        self.outputs['num2'] = self.inputs['num1'] * 5
```

Now one can do something like:

```
n1 = Node1()
n1.inputs['a'] = 5
n1.inputs['b'] = 15

n2 = Node2()
n2.inputs['num1'] = n1.outputs['num2']
n1.run()
n2.run()
```

Now, the problem with this approach is that `n1.outputs['num2']` is only computed after the `run()` function is called on the `n1` object. As far as I am aware, I cannot use references in python, so this code fails as it tries to multiple `None * 5`. A fix is:

```
n1.run()
n2.inputs['num1'] = n1.outputs['num2']
n2.run()
```

However, this is annoying as it makes `specifying` the workflow quite difficult as the connections have to be made after bits of the workflow is run.

Can anyone suggest a good solution for this problem? In C++, I could simply use a reference but I am not sure what to do in this case in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store links to simple values (integers, strings) but you can store them to containers (dict, list).

So you could change your logic to be:

```
n1 = Node1()
n2 = Node1()
n2.connect_input('num1', n1.outputs, 'num2')
```

Where you have the following method:

```
def connect_input(self, input_name, outputs, output_name):
    self.inputs[input_name] = [outputs, output_name]
```

But you would then need to modify your `run` methods to use the following format:

```
def run(self):
    outputs, key = self.inputs['num1']
    self.outputs['num2'] = outputs[key] * 5
```

Comment: I basically thought of this in the shower as well. Basically, just pass the container as well!

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to write a simple workflow/pipeline object in python where one can chain many functions together and execute them in the correct order.

Take a look at [RxPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY).

```
Observable.just({'a': 5, 'b': 15}) \
    .map(lambda x: x['a'] + x['b']) \
    .map(lambda x: x * 5) \
    .subscribe(lambda x: print x)
```

There are lot of operators that let describe quite complicated pipelines.

Comment: This is interesting. In the end, I might just go for one of the libraries.